# Unable to delete from a temp table?

Tags: postgresql

I keep running into an issue where I cannot delete data from a temp table. I can't seem to find relevant hits on Google when I search for the error message though. I tried to set the REPLICA IDENTITY DEFAULT and NOTHING

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE name (LIKE schema.original);
```

> ERROR: cannot delete from table "name" because it does not have a
>   replica identity and publishes deletes Hint: To enable deleting from
>   the table, set REPLICA IDENTITY using ALTER TABLE.

I am trying to follow an ETL example, so my query looks very similar to the one found on this link (the table names and columns are different):

https://github.com/gtoonstra/etl-with-airflow/blob/master/examples/etl-example/sql/process_customer_dimension.sql

My searches keep bring up hits for Logical replication, but when I check my settings I see that it is under replica.

```
name,setting
wal_level,replica
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try to set identity to complete, with will use the whole row as identifier `ALTER TABLE name REPLICA IDENTITY FULL;`

or if it has a unique index
`ALTER TABLE name REPLICA IDENTITY USING INDEX index_name;`

It will use the primary key by default, and I suppose there isn't one.

On a side note, why are you publishing a temp table?
I think you should remove it, as I see no point in replicating the `temp` table. Find your pub name `SELECT * FROM pg_publication;` and delete temp table from it: `ALTER PUBLICATION name DROP TABLE [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [, ...]`

Comment: I began to respond to you that I have no publications, but when I SELECT * from pg_publication, sure enough, there was one. I do not have replication set up currently but I did experiment with it when PG10 first released. I thought I stopped it though. Let me try again.

Comment: Dropping the publication fixed my issue. I must have had a publication running for no reason for months now accidentally.. I wonder if it was impacting performance that whole time. Thanks!

Comment: what happens in the subscription when a table is dropped in publication?